# Check applied coupons before adding a fee in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, fee

I am using some code to add a custom fee at checkout in Woocommerce, however when applying a coupon it does not deduct the fee.

Is there a way to check if a coupon has been used before adding the fee? That is any coupon at all not a specific one.

Code so far is

```
global $woocommerce;

if (empty($woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons))  {

    add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','endo_handling_fee' );
    function endo_handling_fee() {
         global $woocommerce;

         if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
              return;

         $fee = 1.50;
         $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Transaction Fee', $fee, true, 'standard' );
    }

}
```

So you can see I am trying to add an if statement for coupons however this shows the fee whether there is a coupon or not. So I am stuck, any help hugely appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Coupons never deduc the fee… they are only applied to cart contents (cart items)…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a little outdated and you need to add your If statement inside the function instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','endo_handling_fee', 10, 1 );
function endo_handling_fee( $cart ) {
     if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
          return;

     if ( sizeof( $cart->get_applied_coupons() ) > 0 )
          return;

     $fee = 1.50;
     $cart->add_fee( __("Transaction Fee"), $fee, true );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **Note:** Coupon discounts are applied only on cart items. They don't care about Fees.